# difficulty in using HttpGet to login?

Tags: php, android, http

This activity is used for login.
It post the username and password to a PHP verify file by "GET" which will a response(either SUCCESS or FAILED)would be got.
But it can only show "error occure" (neither SUCCESS nor FAILED)
here are the code:

```
public class Login extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    findViewsById();
    setListeners();
}
private Button btn_login;
private EditText edt_username;
private EditText edt_password;

private void findViewsById() {
    edt_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_username);
    edt_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_password);
    btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);              
}


private void setListeners(){
    btn_login.setOnClickListener(login);
}
private Button.OnClickListener login = new Button. OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
   new startLogin().execute();      
}



};

private class startLogin extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> {

    String result;
    String url = "http://www.abc.com/verify.php";
    String fail = "FAILED";
    String error = "error";
    final ProgressDialog progDlg = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);

    String username = edt_username.getText().toString();
    String password = edt_password.getText().toString();


    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progDlg.setTitle("Please wait");
        progDlg.setMessage("Loading...");
        progDlg.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
        progDlg.setCancelable(false);
        progDlg.show();


        //add username and password to the site

        url += "?username=" + username;
        url += "&password="  + password;    

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        try {



            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet (url) ;
            httpResponse = new DefaultHttpClient().execute (httpGet);

            if(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){      
                    result = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());     
                }    
                else{                           
                    //connection error    
                    result = error;
                }    


        } catch  (ClientProtocolException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();

           } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused){

        if (result == fail) {
            progDlg.cancel();
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, R.string.fail, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  //R.string.fail = "username or password is wrong"
        } else if (result == error) {
            progDlg.cancel();
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, R.string.error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //R.string.error = "there is a connection error"
        }
        else if (result == "SUCCESS"){
            progDlg.cancel();
            Intent it = new Intent ();
            it.setClass (Login.this, Main.class);
            startActivity (it);

        } else{
            progDlg.cancel();
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "error occure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }


}}
```

Here are the verify file:

```
<?php
$username = $_GET["username"];
$password = $_GET["password"];
$ourFileName = "users/" . $username . ".txt";
    if (file_exists($ourFileName))
     {
    $fh = fopen($ourFileName, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, 1024);
fclose($fh);

if ($password == $theData)
{
    echo SUCCESS;
}  else
{
    echo FAILED;
}
    }else  {
            echo FAILED;}
     ?>
```

LogCat

```
07-05 13:10:57.065: W/ActivityThread(274): Application com.android.safe is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
07-05 13:10:57.085: I/System.out(274): Sending WAIT chunk
07-05 13:10:57.155: I/dalvikvm(274): Debugger is active
07-05 13:10:57.285: I/System.out(274): Debugger has connected
07-05 13:10:57.285: I/System.out(274): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-05 13:10:57.486: I/System.out(274): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-05 13:10:57.685: I/System.out(274): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-05 13:10:57.885: I/System.out(274): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-05 13:10:58.095: I/System.out(274): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-05 13:10:58.295: I/System.out(274): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-05 13:10:58.495: I/System.out(274): waiting for debugger to settle...
07-05 13:10:58.695: I/System.out(274): debugger has settled (1326)
07-05 13:10:58.985: D/dalvikvm(274): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 805 objects / 58072 bytes in 43ms
07-05 13:10:59.255: D/dalvikvm(274): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 222 objects / 10616 bytes in 42ms
07-05 13:11:45.615: W/KeyCharacterMap(274): No keyboard for id 0
07-05 13:11:45.615: W/KeyCharacterMap(274): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
07-05 13:12:05.345: D/dalvikvm(274): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6458 objects / 265088 bytes in 138ms
07-05 13:12:08.036: W/System.err(274): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 52: http://panel.o-safe.net/vb_verify.php?username=guest &password=guest
07-05 13:12:08.046: W/System.err(274):  at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:970)
07-05 13:12:08.046: W/System.err(274):  at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:75)
07-05 13:12:08.046: W/System.err(274):  at com.android.safe.Login$startLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:100)
07-05 13:12:08.056: W/System.err(274):  at com.android.safe.Login$startLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
07-05 13:12:08.056: W/System.err(274):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
07-05 13:12:08.056: W/System.err(274):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-05 13:12:08.066: W/System.err(274):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-05 13:12:08.066: W/System.err(274):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
07-05 13:12:08.066: W/System.err(274):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
07-05 13:12:08.066: W/System.err(274):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
07-05 13:12:08.076: D/AndroidRuntime(274): Shutting down VM
07-05 13:12:08.076: W/dalvikvm(274): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
07-05 13:12:08.116: E/AndroidRuntime(274): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-05 13:12:08.116: E/AndroidRuntime(274): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-05 13:12:08.116: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.android.safe.Login$startLogin.onPostExecute(Login.java:127)
07-05 13:12:08.116: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.android.safe.Login$startLogin.onPostExecute(Login.java:1)
07-05 13:12:08.116: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
07-05 13:12:08.116: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
07-05 13:12:08.116: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
07-05 13:12:08.116: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-05 13:12:08.116: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-05 13:12:08.116: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-05 13:12:08.116: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 13:12:08.116: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-05 13:12:08.116: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-05 13:12:08.116: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-05 13:12:08.116: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Do you receive a code 200 (HTTP_OK) ? Maybe your url is bad (404) or your php script is wrong...

Comment: have you tested this PHP login script via browser and verified that it works ?

Comment: devMatt: if(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){      
                    result = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());     
                }    
                else{                              
                    result = error;}

no error is received

Comment: sunil: tried and it can show SUCCESS

Comment: Nice code,helped me with my project!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please make sure that the PHP script works fine by checking the same on a browser

i noticed the following errors in your code

- you compare two strings using `==` rather than `equals` method in 'String' class. so change all `==` `result` comparisons to `equals` in `onPostExecute` method.

updated code

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void unused){

    if (result.equals(fail)) {
        progDlg.cancel();
        Toast.makeText(Login.this, R.string.fail, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  //R.string.fail = "username or password is wrong"
    } else if (result.equals(error)) {
        progDlg.cancel();
        Toast.makeText(Login.this, R.string.error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //R.string.error = "there is a connection error"
    }
    else if (result.equals("SUCCESS")){
        progDlg.cancel();
        Intent it = new Intent ();
        it.setClass (Login.this, Main.class);
        startActivity (it);

    } else{
        progDlg.cancel();
        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "error occure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

- One another thing. you can return values from 'doInBackGround' method to `onPostExecute` method. what i mean is, it is not necessary that you always make changes to global variables. here variable `result`.  for this you need to change the `AsyncTask` signature while extending it.

so change

```
private class startLogin extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void>
```

to

```
private class startLogin extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String>
```

the third parameter is the `Result` type. Now you have to change the following methods to adapt the above change

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
```

to

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
```

and

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void unused){
```

to

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
```

this will help you to return status strings directly from `doInBackGround` method to `onPostExecute`

Comment: sunil: The application has stopped unexpectedly.Please try again.
It happened both SUCCESS and FAILED

Comment: @user1503828 you mean to say, when you updated the code, the application is crashing ? if so, please post the logcat logs

Comment: 07-05 12:29:22.954: E/AndroidRuntime(284): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-05 12:29:22.954: E/AndroidRuntime(284): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-05 12:29:22.954: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at com.android.safe.Login$startLogin.onPostExecute(Login.java:127)
07-05 12:29:22.954: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at com.android.safe.Login$startLogin.onPostExecute(Login.java:1)
07-05 12:29:22.954: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
07-05 12:29:22.954: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)

Comment: 07-05 12:29:22.954: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
07-05 12:29:22.954: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-05 12:29:22.954: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-05 12:29:22.954: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-05 12:29:22.954: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

Comment: 07-05 12:29:22.954: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-05 12:29:22.954: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-05 12:29:22.954: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-05 12:29:22.954: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: @Hinata heyy.. please post the logcat logs in your original post itself. logs in comments are very difficult to read. also use code formatting while posting

Comment: the bug have fixed that it is caused by the difference between "guest" and "guest "...
By the way, it also crash if there is no connection to internet.

Comment: @Hinata where does this "guest" 'factor' comes in to picture ? it is not mentioned in this post at all. explain how you solved your issue, so that it may help others also

Comment: @Hinata regarding the connection issue, you have to check whether the device is connected to internet or not, before making connection. there are lot of SO posts on the same issue. search for that. if you doesn't get an answer please post another question